# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'librosa'

Tags: python, voice-recognition, librosa

Currently I am working on voice recognition where I wanted to use Librosa library.

I install librosa with the command on ubuntu:

```
conda install -c conda-forge librosa
```

But when I run the code I got the following error:

```
import librosa
```

---

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-989066361697> in <module>
----> 1 import librosa

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'librosa'
```

Can anyone tell me how to use librosa?

Comment: Run "which python" on your console and see that it is loading the right one. If conda is installing in one location, but you're calling another Python when you run "import", this would cause the error you observe.

Comment: /home/subhash/anaconda3/bin/python

Comment: and are you sure this is where conda is installing? Try doing "which conda" also

Comment: subhash@subhash-Inspiron-3558:~$ which python
/home/subhash/anaconda3/bin/python
subhash@subhash-Inspiron-3558:~$ which conda
/home/subhash/anaconda3/bin/conda 
.....
my conda path is 
......

/home/subhash/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda....

Comment: very strange. Have you tried installing it without conda? just use pip3 install and see if that works?

Comment: I am on a mac so I can't reproduce this problem, much as I have tried.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numba.decorators'   ..... with pip3.....I didn't understand what u want to say

Comment: okkk... when I installed librosa it goes to python3.8.... How to get rid of it?

Comment: so therein lies the issue - there is indeed a path conflict. Try setting up a virtual environment to solve it. Check out: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/how-to-use-python-virtualenv/

Comment: Restarting Anaconda worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

If you’re using a Python 3.5 environment in conda, you may run into trouble with the numba dependency. This can be avoided by installing from the numba conda channel before installing librosa:

Run this command first in anaconda prompt

`conda install -c numba numba`

and then

`conda install -c conda-forge librosa`

I hope this would help you

Comment: It still give same response. Nothing change.

Comment: ok! its work for me in same problem with specifying version of numba=0.48 and librosa=0.7.2

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions,

1. Try to install librosa by system:

*. First open cmd in system and try one of following commands.

`pip install librosa`

`sudo pip install librosa`

`pip install -u librosa`

2. Or in conda environment:

*. Open appropriate anaconda prompt(according to environment) and try following commands inorder,

First,
`conda install -c numba numba`

Then,
`conda install -c conda-forge librosa`

Answer (score 0):

**What I did**

I had a similar problem. I had to use the following code:

```
sys.path.append(r"C:{pathtopython}\Lib\site-packages")
```

Assuming you downloaded librosa to the path above, then the program will be able to find librosa and use it.

**Why it Works/Why it Happened**

It works because the program is looking in a directory that the package isn't in.

All my other packages were able to be found by my program without using the code above, so I think it's related to the librosa installation.

Answer (score 0):

Do `pip install librosa --user` and then restart Anaconda.

Answer (score -1):

It did not work for me also and I received the same error. Then I cut and pasted the entire code to a new SPYDER document and it worked. Not sure why it did not work the first time in SPYDER. But try pasting into a new SPYDER file and see what happens.