# Getting a ModuleNotFoundError with librosa

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, librosa, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to load the audio files into the NumPy array using this code

```
#%%
import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import IPython.display as ipd
import os, os.path
import time
import joblib
import numpy as np

#%%
fname = 'archive\\Actor_01\\03-01-01-01-01-01-01.wav'

data, sampling_rate = librosa.load(fname)
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
librosa.display.waveshow(data, sr=sampling_rate)

ipd.Audio(fname)

# %%
lst = []

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('archive'):
    for file in files:
        try:
            X, sample_rate = librosa.load(os.path.join(subdir, file), res_type='kaiser_fast')
            mfccs = np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=X, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40).T, axis=0)
            file_class = int(file[7:8]) - 1
            arr = mfccs, file_class
            lst.append(arr)
        except ValueError as err:
            print(err)
            continue
```

Everything runs fine except I am getting an error at line 25

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\powellt1\Documents\COMP5500\NonGitSED\algorithm.py in line 7
      23 for file in files:
      24     try:
----> 25         X, sample_rate = librosa.load(os.path.join(subdir, file), res_type='kaiser_fast')
      26         mfccs = np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=X, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40).T, axis=0)
      27         file_class = int(file[7:8]) - 1
File c:\Users\powellt1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py:193, in load(path, sr, mono, offset, duration, dtype, res_type)
    190     y = to_mono(y)
    192 if sr is not None:
--> 193     y = resample(y, orig_sr=sr_native, target_sr=sr, res_type=res_type)
    195 else:
    196     sr = sr_native

File c:\Users\powellt1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py:684, in resample(y, orig_sr, target_sr, res_type, fix, scale, axis, **kwargs)
    675     y_hat = np.apply_along_axis(
    676         soxr.resample,
    677         axis=axis,
   (...)
    681         quality=res_type,
    682     )
    683 else:
--> 684     y_hat = resampy.resample(y, orig_sr, target_sr, filter=res_type, axis=axis)
```

I know I have librosa installed properly and it works in the previous cells.

I've tried to reinstall and verify the installation of librosa and I've tried using

```
from librosa.core import load
```

but nothing seems to be working to fix the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out after coming through the documentation that you have to install resampy package separately from the librosa package itself. After installing the package I was able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

First try this: `To check all the installed Python modules, we can use the following two commands with the 'pip': Using 'pip freeze' command. Using 'pip list command.` you should run pip with the same way you run your program, for example: `python -m pip ...` if you cant find librosa, try installing it the `python -m` way. If you find it and it doesn't load, try loading it in the installation directory for example.

EDIT: [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'librosa'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658071/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-librosa) this article states that it could also be a dependency error, try installing those too, with `python -m pip`

Comment: I was able to find librosa and it does work in the previous use "data, sampling_rate = librosa.load(fname)" but I am getting the error for the specific use of librosa stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see , the ModuleNotFoundError is not for Librosa module at all. It is for a module that is used either within the librosa module or you are passing in the wrong dimensions (not likely , but check.)

Also, check if there is any filter names 'kaiser_fast' , I think that is what is causing error.

Comment: According to the resample_type documentation, there is a type called 'kaiser_fast'. https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.resample.html#librosa.resample